# What is an optional value in Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2):

> You can use `if` and `let` together to work with values that might be missing. These values are represented as optionals. An optional value either contains a value or contains `nil` to indicate that the value is missing. Write a question mark (`?`) after the type of a value to mark the value as optional.

Why would you want to use an optional value?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift

Comment: Optional can also be viewed as an implementation of the [Option / Maybe monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type). This [blog here](http://www.javiersoto.me/post/106875422394) does a good job of trying to explain what is otherwise a difficult concept.

Comment: tldr: “Swift needs you to be clear about when a value can be missing and when it's guaranteed to exist.” from nevan king’s [excellent answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026093)

Answer (score 570, accepted):

An optional in Swift is a type that can hold either a value or no value. Optionals are written by appending a `?` to any type:

```
var name: String? = "Bertie"
```

Optionals (along with Generics) are one of the most difficult Swift concepts to understand. Because of how they are written and used, it's easy to get a wrong idea of what they are. Compare the optional above to creating a normal String:

```
var name: String = "Bertie" // No "?" after String
```

From the syntax it looks like an optional String is very similar to an ordinary String. It's not. An optional String is not a String with some "optional" setting turned on. It's not a special variety of String. A String and an optional String are completely different types.

Here's the most important thing to know: An optional is a kind of container. An optional String is a container which might contain a String. An optional Int is a container which might contain an Int. Think of an optional as a kind of parcel. Before you open it (or "unwrap" in the language of optionals) you won't know if it contains something or nothing.

You can see [how optionals are implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift) in the Swift Standard Library by typing "Optional" into any Swift file and ⌘-clicking on it. Here's the important part of the definition:

```
enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case none
    case some(Wrapped)
}
```

Optional is just an `enum` which can be one of two cases: `.none` or `.some`. If it's `.some`, there's an associated value which, in the example above, would be the `String` "Hello". An optional uses Generics to give a type to the associated value. The type of an optional String isn't `String`, it's `Optional`, or more precisely `Optional<String>`.

Everything Swift does with optionals is magic to make reading and writing code more fluent. Unfortunately this obscures the way it actually works. I'll go through some of the tricks later.

**Note:** I'll be talking about optional variables a lot, but it's fine to create optional constants too. I mark all variables with their type to make it easier to understand type types being created, but you don't have to in your own code.

---

### How to create optionals

To create an optional, append a `?` after the type you wish to wrap. Any type can be optional, even your own custom types. You can't have a space between the type and the `?`.

```
var name: String? = "Bob" // Create an optional String that contains "Bob"
var peter: Person? = Person() // An optional "Person" (custom type)

// A class with a String and an optional String property
class Car {
var modelName: String // must exist
var internalName: String? // may or may not exist
}
```

---

### Using optionals

You can compare an optional to `nil` to see if it has a value:

```
var name: String? = "Bob"
name = nil // Set name to nil, the absence of a value
if name != nil {
    print("There is a name")
}
if name == nil { // Could also use an "else"
    print("Name has no value")
}
```

This is a little confusing. It implies that an optional is either one thing or another. It's either nil or it's "Bob". This is not true, the optional doesn't transform into something else. Comparing it to nil is a trick to make easier-to-read code. If an optional equals nil, this just means that the enum is currently set to `.none`.

---

### Only optionals can be nil

If you try to set a non-optional variable to nil, you'll get an error.

```
var red: String = "Red"
red = nil // error: nil cannot be assigned to type 'String'
```

Another way of looking at optionals is as a complement to normal Swift variables. They are a counterpart to a variable which is guaranteed to have a value. Swift is a careful language that hates ambiguity. Most variables are define as non-optionals, but sometimes this isn't possible. For example, imagine a view controller which loads an image either from a cache or from the network. It may or may not have that image at the time the view controller is created. There's no way to guarantee the value for the image variable. In this case you would have to make it optional. It starts as `nil` and when the image is retrieved, the optional gets a value.

Using an optional reveals the programmers intent. Compared to Objective-C, where any object could be nil, Swift needs you to be clear about when a value can be missing and when it's guaranteed to exist.

---

### To use an optional, you "unwrap" it

An optional `String` cannot be used in place of an actual `String`. To use the wrapped value inside an optional, you have to unwrap it. The simplest way to unwrap an optional is to add a `!` after the optional name. This is called "force unwrapping". It returns the value inside the optional (as the original type) but if the optional is `nil`, it causes a runtime crash. Before unwrapping you should be sure there's a value.

```
var name: String? = "Bob"
let unwrappedName: String = name!
print("Unwrapped name: \(unwrappedName)")

name = nil
let nilName: String = name! // Runtime crash. Unexpected nil.
```

---

### Checking and using an optional

Because you should always check for nil before unwrapping and using an optional, this is a common pattern:

```
var mealPreference: String? = "Vegetarian"
if mealPreference != nil {
    let unwrappedMealPreference: String = mealPreference!
    print("Meal: \(unwrappedMealPreference)") // or do something useful
}
```

In this pattern you check that a value is present, then when you are sure it is, you force unwrap it into a temporary constant to use. Because this is such a common thing to do, Swift offers a shortcut using "if let". This is called "optional binding".

```
var mealPreference: String? = "Vegetarian"
if let unwrappedMealPreference: String = mealPreference {
    print("Meal: \(unwrappedMealPreference)") 
}
```

This creates a temporary constant (or variable if you replace `let` with `var`) whose scope is only within the if's braces. Because having to use a name like "unwrappedMealPreference" or "realMealPreference" is a burden, Swift allows you to reuse the original variable name, creating a temporary one within the bracket scope

```
var mealPreference: String? = "Vegetarian"
if let mealPreference: String = mealPreference {
    print("Meal: \(mealPreference)") // separate from the other mealPreference
}
```

Here's some code to demonstrate that a different variable is used:

```
var mealPreference: String? = "Vegetarian"
if var mealPreference: String = mealPreference {
    print("Meal: \(mealPreference)") // mealPreference is a String, not a String?
    mealPreference = "Beef" // No effect on original
}
// This is the original mealPreference
print("Meal: \(mealPreference)") // Prints "Meal: Optional("Vegetarian")"
```

Optional binding works by checking to see if the optional equals nil. If it doesn't, it unwraps the optional into the provided constant and executes the block. In Xcode 8.3 and later (Swift 3.1), trying to print an optional like this will cause a useless warning. Use the optional's `debugDescription` to silence it:

```
print("\(mealPreference.debugDescription)")
```

---

### What are optionals for?

Optionals have two use cases:

1. Things that can fail (I was expecting something but I got nothing)
2. Things that are nothing now but might be something later (and vice-versa)

Some concrete examples:

- A property which can be there or not there, like `middleName` or `spouse` in a `Person` class
- A method which can return a value or nothing, like searching for a match in an array
- A method which can return either a result or get an error and return nothing, like trying to read a file's contents (which normally returns the file's data) but the file doesn't exist
- Delegate properties, which don't always have to be set and are generally set after initialization
- For `weak` properties in classes. The thing they point to can be set to `nil` at any time
- A large resource that might have to be released to reclaim memory
- When you need a way to know when a value has been set (data not yet loaded > the data) instead of using a separate dataLoaded `Boolean`

Optionals don't exist in Objective-C but there is an equivalent concept, returning nil. Methods that can return an object can return nil instead. This is taken to mean "the absence of a valid object" and is often used to say that something went wrong. It only works with Objective-C objects, not with primitives or basic C-types (enums, structs). Objective-C often had specialized types to represent the absence of these values (`NSNotFound` which is really `NSIntegerMax`, `kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid` to represent an invalid coordinate, `-1` or some negative value are also used). The coder has to know about these special values so they must be documented and learned for each case. If a method can't take `nil` as a parameter, this has to be documented. In Objective-C, `nil` was a pointer just as all objects were defined as pointers, but `nil` pointed to a specific (zero) address. In Swift, `nil` is a literal which means the absence of a certain type.

---

### Comparing to `nil`

You used to be able to use any optional as a `Boolean`:

```
let leatherTrim: CarExtras? = nil
if leatherTrim {
    price = price + 1000
}
```

In more recent versions of Swift you have to use `leatherTrim != nil`. Why is this? The problem is that a `Boolean` can be wrapped in an optional. If you have `Boolean` like this:

```
var ambiguous: Boolean? = false
```

it has two kinds of "false", one where there is no value and one where it has a value but the value is `false`. Swift hates ambiguity so now you must always check an optional against `nil`.

You might wonder what the point of an optional `Boolean` is? As with other optionals the `.none` state could indicate that the value is as-yet unknown. There might be something on the other end of a network call which takes some time to poll. Optional Booleans are also called "[Three-Value Booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)"

---

### Swift tricks

Swift uses some tricks to allow optionals to work. Consider these three lines of ordinary looking optional code;

```
var religiousAffiliation: String? = "Rastafarian"
religiousAffiliation = nil
if religiousAffiliation != nil { ... }
```

None of these lines should compile.

- The first line sets an optional String using a String literal, two different types. Even if this was a `String` the types are different
- The second line sets an optional String to nil, two different types
- The third line compares an optional string to nil, two different types

I'll go through some of the implementation details of optionals that allow these lines to work.

---

### Creating an optional

Using `?` to create an optional is syntactic sugar, enabled by the Swift compiler. If you want to do it the long way, you can create an optional like this:

```
var name: Optional<String> = Optional("Bob")
```

This calls `Optional`'s first initializer, `public init(_ some: Wrapped)`, which infers the optional's associated type from the type used within the parentheses.

The even longer way of creating and setting an optional:

```
var serialNumber:String? = Optional.none
serialNumber = Optional.some("1234")
print("\(serialNumber.debugDescription)")
```

---

### Setting an optional to `nil`

You can create an optional with no initial value, or create one with the initial value of `nil` (both have the same outcome).

```
var name: String?
var name: String? = nil
```

Allowing optionals to equal `nil` is enabled by the protocol `ExpressibleByNilLiteral` (previously named `NilLiteralConvertible`). The optional is created with `Optional`'s second initializer, `public init(nilLiteral: ())`. The docs say that you shouldn't use `ExpressibleByNilLiteral` for anything except optionals, since that would change the meaning of nil in your code, but it's possible to do it:

```
class Clint: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    var name: String?
    required init(nilLiteral: ()) {
        name = "The Man with No Name"
    }
}

let clint: Clint = nil // Would normally give an error
print("\(clint.name)")
```

The same protocol allows you to set an already-created optional to `nil`. Although it's not recommended, you can use the nil literal initializer directly:

```
var name: Optional<String> = Optional(nilLiteral: ())
```

---

### Comparing an optional to `nil`

Optionals define two special "==" and "!=" operators, which you can see in the `Optional` definition. The first `==` allows you to check if any optional is equal to nil. Two different optionals which are set to .none will always be equal if the associated types are the same. When you compare to nil, behind the scenes Swift creates an optional of the same associated type, set to .none then uses that for the comparison.

```
// How Swift actually compares to nil
var tuxedoRequired: String? = nil
let temp: Optional<String> = Optional.none
if tuxedoRequired == temp { // equivalent to if tuxedoRequired == nil
    print("tuxedoRequired is nil")
}
```

The second `==` operator allows you to compare two optionals. Both have to be the same type and that type needs to conform to `Equatable` (the protocol which allows comparing things with the regular "==" operator). Swift (presumably) unwraps the two values and compares them directly. It also handles the case where one or both of the optionals are `.none`. Note the distinction between comparing to the `nil` literal.

Furthermore, it allows you to compare any `Equatable` type to an optional wrapping that type:

```
let numberToFind: Int = 23
let numberFromString: Int? = Int("23") // Optional(23)
if numberToFind == numberFromString {
    print("It's a match!") // Prints "It's a match!"
}
```

Behind the scenes, Swift wraps the non-optional as an optional before the comparison. It works with literals too (`if 23 == numberFromString {`)

I said there are two `==` operators, but there's actually a third which allow you to put `nil` on the left-hand side of the comparison

```
if nil == name { ... }
```

---

### Naming Optionals

There is no Swift convention for naming optional types differently from non-optional types. People avoid adding something to the name to show that it's an optional (like "optionalMiddleName", or "possibleNumberAsString") and let the declaration show that it's an optional type. This gets difficult when you want to name something to hold the value from an optional. The name "middleName" implies that it's a String type, so when you extract the String value from it, you can often end up with names like "actualMiddleName" or "unwrappedMiddleName" or "realMiddleName". Use optional binding and reuse the variable name to get around this.

---

### The official definition

From ["The Basics" in the Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_399):

> Swift also introduces optional types, which handle the absence of a value. Optionals say either “there is a value, and it equals x” or “there isn’t a value at all”. Optionals are similar to using nil with pointers in Objective-C, but they work for any type, not just classes. Optionals are safer and more expressive than nil pointers in Objective-C and are at the heart of many of Swift’s most powerful features.
>
> Optionals are an example of the fact that Swift is a type safe language. Swift helps you to be clear about the types of values your code can work with. If part of your code expects a String, type safety prevents you from passing it an Int by mistake. This enables you to catch and fix errors as early as possible in the development process.

---

To finish, here's a poem from 1899 about optionals:

*Yesterday upon the stair

I met a man who wasn’t there

He wasn’t there again today

I wish, I wish he’d go away*
[*Antigonish*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigonish_%28poem%29)

---

### More resources:

- [The Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_6)
- [Optionals in Swift (Medium)](https://medium.com/@rrridges/swift-optionals-a10dcfd8aab5)
- [WWDC Session 402 "Introduction to Swift" (starts around 14:15)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/402/)
- [More optional tips and tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil)

Comment: var myOtherString:String = "Hello"; if myOtherString {
    println(myOtherString)
}; Gives me "Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'Logic Value'"

Comment: @bluesm You're right. Not sure where that other error came from. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Following in you example, what would be the output of var nameString:String? = nil

if nameString {
    println("\(nameString) requests the pleasure of your company")
} else {
    println("We request the pleasure of your company")
}

Comment: Steve is never an optional!

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu Unfortunately Steve is very much an optional. He was here and now he's not.

Comment: `if myString` doesn't compile anymore. You need `if myString != nil`. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_483).

Comment: hi, is this the same pattern as the "maybe" pattern as outlined in the famous blog post that talked about the "billion dollar mistake" of null pointer?

Comment: best and clearest explanation for ? and ! use in Swift I found on the web. thank you

Comment: [mateo](http://matteomanferdini.com/the-complete-guide-to-understanding-swift-optionals/) explains in depth the Optionals, reaching in Depth and easy examples.

Comment: If I use **!** in place of **?**, then also I get the same result. Can anybody tell the difference between using ? and /

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, it is much clearer than Apple's own documentation.

Comment: if objectNotNil like in Objective-C is the best safety way. I wish Optional will gone away too, let the compiler say "hey, it's not safe, please fixed like..."

Comment: Holy crap, the only tutorial that helped me understand optionals correctly. Brilliant work my friend @nevanking

Comment: Good article on this topic : http://iosrock.blogspot.com/2018/09/lets-understand-what-is-optional-in.html

Comment: Most complete answer ever on stackoverflow. You are really a king mister "nevan king".

Comment: I keep seeing syntax like this: `foo?.bar?.coollDude()` in this situation does the "?" do the same or something completely different than the above answer?

Comment: Under Swift Tricks (var religiousAffiliation: String? = "Rastafarian") it says none of these lines should compile. Under Swift 5.0 (and probably earlier). They all do now but at the time of this post (Swift 1.0?) I'll take it they would not. By far the best description of Optional that I have ever read. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Let's take the example of an `NSError`, if there isn't an error being returned you'd want to make it optional to return Nil. There's no point in assigning a value to it if there isn't an error..

```
var error: NSError? = nil
```

This also allows you to have a default value. So you can set a method a default value if the function isn't passed anything

```
func doesntEnterNumber(x: Int? = 5) -> Bool {
    if (x == 5){
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: The sentence "If it's nil, the result of any expression with it is nil as well" is simply wrong. `func isNil<T>(t: T?) -> Bool { return t == nil }` will return `true` even if there is a optional value which is `nil` in the expression.

Comment: Incredibly bad code sample. Couldn't you think of something better? Why not simply `return x == 5`? What is so special about 5?

Comment: Nope, 2 years ago I couldn't think of something better. Today yes, but does this get the point across? yes. Thanks for the input @Atomosk, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 12):

You can't have a variable that points to `nil` in Swift — there are no pointers, and no null pointers. But in an API, you often want to be able to indicate either a specific kind of value, or a lack of value — e.g. does my window have a delegate, and if so, who is it? Optionals are Swift's type-safe, memory-safe way to do this.

Answer (score 12):

I made a short answer, that sums up most of the above, to clean the uncertainty that was in my head as a beginner:

Opposed to Objective-C, no variable can contain **nil** in Swift, so the Optional variable type was added (variables suffixed by "?"):

```
    var aString = nil //error
```

The big difference is that the Optional variables don't directly store values (as a normal Obj-C variables would) they contain **two states**: "**has a value**" or "**has nil**":

```
    var aString: String? = "Hello, World!"
    aString = nil //correct, now it contains the state "has nil"
```

That being, you can check those variables in different situations:

```
if let myString = aString? {
     println(myString)
}
else { 
     println("It's nil") // this will print in our case
}
```

By using the "!" suffix, you can also access the values wrapped in them, **only if those exist**. (i.e it is not **nil**):

```
let aString: String? = "Hello, World!"
// var anotherString: String = aString //error
var anotherString: String = aString!

println(anotherString) //it will print "Hello, World!"
```

That's why you need to use "?" and "!" and not use all of them by default. (this was my biggest bewilderment)

I also agree with the answer above: *Optional type cannot be used as a boolean*.

Answer (score 7):

In objective C variables with no value were equal to 'nil'(it was also possible to use 'nil' values same as 0 and false), hence it was possible to use variables in conditional statements (Variables having values are same as 'TRUE' and those with no values were equal to 'FALSE').

Swift provides type safety by providing 'optional value'. i.e. It prevents errors formed from assigning variables of different types.

So in Swift, only booleans can be provided on conditional statements.

```
var hw = "Hello World"
```

Here, even-though 'hw' is a string, it can't be used in an if statement like in objective C.

```
//This is an error

if hw

 {..}
```

For that it needs to be created as,

```
var nhw : String? = "Hello World"

//This is correct

if nhw

 {..}
```

Answer (score 5):

Optional value allows you to show absence of value. Little bit like NULL in SQL or NSNull in Objective-C. I guess this will be an improvement as you can use this even for "primitive" types.

```
// Reimplement the Swift standard library's optional type
enum OptionalValue<T> {
    case None
    case Some(T)
}
var possibleInteger: OptionalValue<Int> = .None
possibleInteger = .Some(100)”
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/gb/jEUH0.l

Comment: `nil` is just syntactic sugar for the enum constant `OptionalValue<T>.None` (where `T` is the type appropriate to the context where you're using `nil`). `?` is a shortcut for `OptionalValue<T>.Some(T)`.

Answer (score 4):

An optional means that Swift is not entirely sure if the value corresponds to the type: for example, Int? means that Swift is not entirely sure whether the number is an Int.

> To remove it, there are three methods you could employ.

1. If you are absolutely sure of the type, you can use an exclamation mark to force unwrap it, like this:

   // Here is an optional variable:

   var age: Int?

   // Here is how you would force unwrap it:

   var unwrappedAge = age!

If you do force unwrap an optional and it is equal to nil, you may encounter this crash error:

[image]

This is not necessarily safe, so here's a method that might prevent crashing in case you are not certain of the type and value:

> Methods 2 and three safeguard against this problem.

2. The Implicitly Unwrapped Optional

   if let unwrappedAge = age {

   // continue in here

   }

> Note that the unwrapped type is now **Int**, rather than **Int?**.

3. The guard statement

   guard let unwrappedAge = age else {
   // continue in here
   }

From here, you can go ahead and use the unwrapped variable. Make sure only to force unwrap (with an !), if you are sure of the type of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

**When i started to learn `Swift` it was very difficult to realize why optional**.

Lets think in this way.
Let consider a class `Person` which has two property `name` and `company`.

```
class Person: NSObject {
    
    var name : String //Person must have a value so its no marked as optional
    var companyName : String? ///Company is optional as a person can be unemployed that is nil value is possible
    
    init(name:String,company:String?) {
        
        self.name = name
        self.companyName = company
        
    }
}
```

Now lets create few objects of `Person`

```
var tom:Person = Person.init(name: "Tom", company: "Apple")//posible
var bob:Person = Person.init(name: "Bob", company:nil) // also Possible because company is marked as optional so we can give Nil
```

But we can not pass `Nil` to `name`

```
var personWithNoName:Person = Person.init(name: nil, company: nil)
```

Now Lets talk about why we use `optional?`.
Lets consider a situation where we want to add  `Inc` after company name like `apple` will be `apple Inc`. We need to append `Inc` after company name and print.

```
print(tom.companyName+" Inc") ///Error saying optional is not unwrapped.
print(tom.companyName!+" Inc") ///Error Gone..we have forcefully unwrap it which is wrong approach..Will look in Next line
print(bob.companyName!+" Inc") ///Crash!!!because bob has no company and nil can be unwrapped.
```

Now lets study why optional takes into place.

```
if let companyString:String = bob.companyName{///Compiler safely unwrap company if not nil.If nil,no unwrap.
    
    print(companyString+" Inc") //Will never executed and no crash!!!
}
```

Lets replace `bob` with `tom`

```
if let companyString:String = tom.companyName{///Compiler safely unwrap company if not nil.If nil,no unwrap.
    
    print(companyString+" Inc") //Will executed and no crash!!!
}
```

And **Congratulation!** we have properly deal with `optional?`

So the realization points are

1. We will mark a variable as optional if its possible to be `nil`
2. If we want to use this variable somewhere in code compiler will
   remind you that we need to check if we have proper deal with that variable
   if it contain `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets Experiment with below code  **Playground**.I Hope will clear idea what is optional and reason of using it.

```
var sampleString: String? ///Optional, Possible to be nil

sampleString = nil ////perfactly valid as its optional

sampleString = "some value"  //Will hold the value

if let value = sampleString{ /// the sampleString is placed into value with auto force upwraped.

    print(value+value)  ////Sample String merged into Two
}

sampleString = nil // value is nil and the

if let value = sampleString{

    print(value + value)  ///Will Not execute and safe for nil checking
}

//   print(sampleString! + sampleString!)  //this line Will crash as + operator can not add nil
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html:

> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties, methods, and subscripts on an optional that might currently be nil. If the optional contains a value, the property, method, or subscript call succeeds; if the optional is nil, the property, method, or subscript call returns nil. Multiple queries can be chained together, and the entire chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is nil.

To understand deeper, read the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

> **? (Optional)** indicates your variable may contain a nil value while **! (unwrapper)** indicates your variable must have a memory (or value) when it is used (tried to get a value from it) at runtime.

The main difference is that optional chaining fails gracefully when the optional is nil, whereas forced unwrapping triggers a runtime error when the optional is nil.

To reflect the fact that optional chaining can be called on a nil value, the result of an optional chaining call is always an optional value, even if the property, method, or subscript you are querying returns a nonoptional value. You can use this optional return value to check whether the optional chaining call was successful (the returned optional contains a value), or did not succeed due to a nil value in the chain (the returned optional value is nil).

Specifically, the result of an optional chaining call is of the same type as the expected return value, but wrapped in an optional. A property that normally returns an Int will return an *Int?* when accessed through optional chaining.

```
var defaultNil : Int?  // declared variable with default nil value
println(defaultNil) >> nil  

var canBeNil : Int? = 4
println(canBeNil) >> optional(4)

canBeNil = nil
println(canBeNil) >> nil

println(canBeNil!) >> // Here nil optional variable is being unwrapped using ! mark (symbol), that will show runtime error. Because a nil optional is being tried to get value using unwrapper

var canNotBeNil : Int! = 4
print(canNotBeNil) >> 4

var cantBeNil : Int = 4
cantBeNil = nil // can't do this as it's not optional and show a compile time error
```

Here is basic tutorial in detail, by Apple Developer Committee: [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Answer (score 0):

An optional in Swift is a type that can hold either a value or no value. Optionals are written by appending a **?** to any type:

```
var name: String?
```

You can refer to this link to get knowledge in deep: https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/optionals-in-swift-2b141f12f870

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of errors which are caused by people trying to use a value which is not set, sometime this can cause a crash, in objective c trying to call the methods of a nil object reference would just be ignored, so some piece of your code not executing and the compiler or written code has no way of telling your why. An optional argument let you have variables that can never be nil, and if you try to do build it the compiler can tell you before your code has even had a chance to run, or you can decide that its appropriate for the object to be undefined, and then the compiler can tell you when you try to write something that doesn't take this into account.

In the case of calling a possible nil object you can just go

```
object?.doSomthing()
```

You have made it explicit to the compiler and any body who reads your code, that its possible object is nil and nothing will happen. Some times you have a few lines of code you only want to occur if the value exists, so you can do

```
if let obj = object {
    obj.doSomthing()
    doSomethingto(obj)
}
```

The two statements will only execute if object is something, simarly you may want to stop the rest of the entire block of code if its not something

```
guard let obj = object {
    return
}
obj.doSomthing()
doSomethingto(obj)
```

This can be simpler to read if everything after is only applicable if object is something, another possiblity is you want to use a default value

```
let obj = object ?? <default-object>
obj.doSomthing()
doSomethingto(obj)
```

Now obj will be assigned to something even if its a default value for the type

options are useful in situation where a value may not gain a value until some event has occurred or you can use setting an option to nil as a way to say its no longer relevant or needs to be set again and everything that uses it has no point it doing anything with it until it is set, one way I like to use optionals is to tell me something has to be done or if has already been done for example

```
func eventFired() {
    guard timer == nil else { return }
    timer = scheduleTimerToCall(method, in: 60)
}

func method() {
    doSomthing()
    timer = nil
}
```

This sudo code can call eventFired many times, but it's only on the first call that a timer is scheduled, once the schedule executes, it runs some method and sets timer back to nil so another timer can be scheduled.

Once you get around your head around variables being in an undefined state you can use that for all sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Optional (in Swift) means a variable/constant can be nullable. You can see that Kotlin language implements the same thing but never calls it an 'optional'. For example:

```swift
var lol: Laugh? = nil
```

is equivalent to this in Kotlin:

```kotlin
var lol: Laugh? = null
```

or this in Java:

```java
@Nullable Laugh lol = null;
```

In the very first example, if you don't use the `?`symbol in front of the object type, then you will have an error. Because the question mark means that the variable/constant can be null, therefore being called optional.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an equivalent optional declaration in Swift:

```
var middleName: String?
```

This declaration creates a variable named middleName of type String. The question mark (?) after the String variable type indicates that the middleName variable can contain a value that can either be a String or nil. Anyone looking at this code immediately knows that middleName can be nil. It's self-documenting!

If you don't specify an initial value for an optional constant or variable (as shown above) the value is automatically set to nil for you. If you prefer, you can explicitly set the initial value to nil:

```
var middleName: String? = nil
```

for more detail for optional read below link

http://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/swift-101-working-swifts-new-optional-values

Comment: use this, var middleName: String! = ""