# Gets an error multiplying Swift Ints

Tags: swift, multiplication

New Swift enthusiast here! I'm following Rey Wenderlich's [Candy Crush tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/75270/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-1) and get an error when multiplying two `Int` values. I know Swift is strictly typed so would be the reason? Am I not allowed to do this in Swift? Note the `error` comments where I'm having trouble. Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

```
class Array2D<T> {
  let columns: Int
  let rows: Int
  let array: Array<T>

  init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
    self.columns = columns
    self.rows = rows
    array = Array<T?>(count: rows*columns, repeatedValue: nil)    // ERROR: could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments
  }

  subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
    get {
        return array[row*columns + column]
    }
    set {
        array[row*columns + column] = newValue   // ERROR: could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ```row*count```?? probably ```rows*columns```...

Comment: I made the change. Thanks! Unfortunately, I get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your array to be of type `T?`.
In the first case, you are trying to assign array of type `T?` to array of type `T`. In the second, you are trying to assign `newValue` of type `T?` to an element of array of type `T`.

Changing the type of the array fixes both these things.

Comment: You're the man Roshan. Does the `T?` mean it could be of any type?

Comment: Nope.. ```T?``` refers to an ''optional'' of type ```T```. It basically says it can hold a value of type ```T``` or no value(```nil```). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift. Of course, ```T``` itself can be any type but once you fix ```T```, ```T?``` is also fixed.

Comment: So you're saying on the first 'error' line, `count` could've been `nil` with the `<T?>`.. OR if it was set to an `Int`, then it would be fixed as an Int?

Comment: ```init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T)``` is the method signature defined for ```Array<T>```. In your case, ```T``` is ```T?```. Therefore ```count``` is ```Int```, not ```Int?``` which means you have to give an integer, not ```nil```. However, ```repeatedValue``` is ```T?```, so you can give a value of type ```T``` OR ```nil```

Comment: This is a little confusing at first, esp. if you have come from Objective-C. ```nil``` gets very special treatment in Swift.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to check out the docs for this case. A little confusing for sure. Thanks tho!