# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) on println() in Xcode 6 beta 7

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, xcode6, println

So, today I downloaded and installed the latest beta of Xcode 6 (beta 7), released yesterday. As per usual, I got bunch of compiling errors due to changes in the program, but nothing major and all fixed within 5 min.

Now, however, I get a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` when trying to do a simple `println()` on a `NSURL`. Have tried on the following `NSDATA` as well, with the same error.

This is my **simple code**:

```
let urlTest: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

println(urlTest)
```

`urlString` contains the URL to a JSON result and is tested fully valid.

So my question is; is there an obvious error in my simple code (quite new to iOS development and of course Swift) or is this some kind of annoying bug in beta 7?

Comment: Did you clean your working directory? This should always be done when a new beta comes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `urlTest` as optional, maybe `NSRUL(string:)` returning nil.

```
let urlTest: NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString)
```

See answer [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Comment: It was in fact returning `nil`. Thought it would print out `nil` then, but it needed to be optional, of course!