# Swift - pathForResource inDirectory parameter

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, nsurl

I'm making a very simple app that uses a UIWebView to display a pdf map that can be zoomed in on, panned, etc.

However, when creating a target url for the pdf, the pathForResource call isn't working right. This is my code:

```
var targetURL : NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: type)
```

I get an error on the parentheses before "filename", that says `Missing argument for parameter 'inDirectory' in call`. I tried adding an argument for this:

```
var targetURL : NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: type, inDirectory: "Map")
```

I don't know what to put for `inDirectory`, because I don't know what the directory is - I added the file to my project and it is in the same folder as my ViewController.swift file. Anyway, it doens't really matter, because I get the following error in the same place, `Extra argument 'inDirectory in call`.

What do I do?

Answer (score 4):

`pathForResource()` does not return a `NSURL` object, but a `String?`. Declare your variable accordingly and it should work.

```
var targetURL : String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: type)
```

Or, of course, if you would rather - just use `URLForResource()` instead.

```
var targetURL : NSURL? = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: type)
```

Comment: any chance you know how to handle a case where targetURL is returned as nil? Is there a way to add a callback/closure to this so I just wait until something is returned?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to answer that I'm afraid, but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24026093/222245) does a pretty good job explaining *optional types*. Perhaps it will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. In my case it was because my variable (in your case `type`) needed to be unwrapped. Adding a bang `!` made the error go away and made the code execute.