# Is 'x?.y' in Swift the same as 'x?' followed by '.y'?

Tags: syntax, swift, member, option-type

I understand that in Swift, if I define

```
var opt:String? = "Optional"
```

I will get an error if I attempt

```
opt.isEmpty
```

since `opt` is of type `String?` which does does not have an `isEmpty` method. And I thought that I understood that

```
opt?.isEmpty
```

does not produce an error because `opt?` unwraps (any non-`nil`) `opt`, resulting in a `String`, which does have an `isEmpty` method. But

```
opt?
```

on its own results in a `String?` and not a `String`.

Is `?.` a different operator from `?` followed by `.`?

---

Try

```
(opt?).isEmpty
```

and get a suggestive error.

Comment: The question is whether `opt?.isEmpty` is different from (roughly) `(opt?).isEmpty` (it sure appears to be) and if so, what's going on when `opt?` is evaluated on its own vs. what happens when it is evaluated as part of optional chaining. Clearly "unwrap (if not `nil`) or leave alone (if `nil`)" would not be an adequate definition of `?`, because that's not how it behaves on its own.

Comment: An effective place to start an answer will be a clear explanation of exactly what `opt?` *own its own does in general* (whether we have `var opt: Type?` or `var opt: Type!`).

Comment: `Type?` and `Type!` are *type annotations*, which is something different than `opt?` or `opt!`. As explained below, `opt?` does nothing "on it's own".

Comment: @MartinR: Not true. When `var opt: Type?` it appears to indeed do nothing; `opt` is the same as `opt?`. When `var opt: Type!` it does do something; `opt` and `opt?` are different. Explaining that is the place to start.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius edited my answer have a look to clarify your doubt.

Comment: @codester: Exactly. So `opt?` does not do "nothing on its own". The question the becomes: (a) what does it do and (b) how is that different from what it does followed by a `.`?

Comment: when followed by `.` it will allow you to unwrap the value return optional value and gracefully terminates if found `nil`i.e (opt?).isEmpty gives error because of bracket and `opt?.isEmpty returning `optional` having `false` value.

Comment: @codester: So, following a `?`, `.` does the unwrapping (if `opt` is not `nil`). `?` itself, does not unwrap? In fact, when own its own, `?` *wraps!* — right? Sorry to be so dim, but the documentation is to blame here: in "This is very similar to placing an exclamation mark (!) after an optional value to force the unwrapping of its value" it sounds like "this" refers to `?`, when in fact it refers (a bit vaguely) to the whole process of optional chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But opt? on its own results in a String? and not a String.

Yes. According to the Swift language reference, Expressions, Postfix Expressions, [Optional-Chaining Expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-XID_838):

> On its own, the postfix ? operator simply returns the value of its
>   argument as an optional.

So putting a `?` by itself at the end of an optional is a complete no-op. It has no effect.

> Is ?. a different operator from ? followed by .?

Yes. More specifically, `?` has the [optional-chaining effect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_356) when used in any "postfix expression", including when followed by `()` (function call), `.` (member access), and `[]` (subscript).

Comment: So in effect, `opt?` is also an optional chaining expression, where the (implicit) postfix operation is identity. And `(x?).y` is different from `x?.y` for the simple reason that only the latter is an optional chaining expression; the former is `y` *applied to the result* of an optional chaining. If I have that right, it all makes sense, and is totally consistent.

Comment: Also: [a question here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/258012/28601) that you might contribute to.

Comment: And one more note for completeness: `?.` is *not* (as I ask at the end of the OP) a different operator from `?` and `.`: "There is one caveat to the rules above. If the `!` or `?` predefined operator has no whitespace on the left, it is treated as a postfix operator, regardless of whether it has whitespace on the right. To use the `?` as the optional-chaining operator, it must not have whitespace on the left."

Answer (score 2):

Yes `opt?.isEmpty` is different from `String?`.It is called [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).From swift programming guide:

> You specify optional chaining by placing a question mark (?) after the
>   optional value on which you wish to call a property, method or
>   subscript if the optional is non-nil. This is very similar to placing
>   an exclamation mark (!) after an optional value to force the
>   unwrapping of its value. The main difference is that optional chaining
>   fails gracefully when the optional is nil, whereas forced unwrapping
>   triggers a runtime error when the optional is nil.

This creates optional as you thinking
     var opt:String?

Now

```
 opt?.isEmpty //it will not crash if opt is nil
```

is same as except

```
opt!.isEmpty //it will crash if opt is nil
```

if `opt!` is `nil` than it will not crash at runtime.Optional chaining is used to call long sequences of optional without calling.Every optional chain returns optional i.e opt? returns optional unwraps it and if nil than not call isEmpty else call isEmpty and reutns value.
Also

```
  (opt?).isEmpty
```

When you  are writing above statement it is just optional(not optional of optional) and it fails to unwrap because of braces.So error is showing

```
$T2?? does not have a member named `isEmpty`
```

to unwrap it use

```
(opt?)!.isEmpty
```

it will return false

**Edit:** To clarify more

```
   var o1 = opt?
   var o2 = ((opt?)?)
```

is doing nothing in its own it just assign same value to `o1`,`o2` i.e String?.
to unwrap `opt` and `o1`,`o2` they both are optional and need single `!` operator to unwrap it.

**Also please do not misunderstood between `String?` and `opt?` they both are different when ? is used after some type in decleration it makes optional and when `?` used after variable `opt`it is used for unwrap in optional chaining and return optional value it is returning**

Extra Stuff:

try this to more clarify

```
(((opt?)?)!).isEmpty     //it will unwrap with single !
((((opt?)?)!)?).isEmpty   //compiler will show suggestion to remove ?
```

the below statement makes optional of optional of optional

```
   var opt:String??? = "Optional"
```

to unwrap

```
   opt!!!.isEmpty
```

**EDIT2**

`opt?` always return optional but if `opt` is defined as String! it is `implicit optional` and `opt?` will return `optional(explicit)`.But if `opt` is already optional `opt?` will do nothing

From swift programming guide

> To put it another way:
>
> ```
> If the type you are trying to retrieve is not optional, it will become optional because of the optional chaining.
> If the type you are trying to retrieve is already optional, it will not become more optional because of the chaining.
> ```
>
> Therefore:
>
> ```
> If you try to retrieve an Int value through optional chaining, an Int? is always returned, no matter how many levels of chaining are used.
> Similarly, if you try to retrieve an Int? value through optional chaining, an Int? is always returned, no matter how many levels of chaining are used.
> ```

Comment: That's not quite the question. See comment above.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius misunderstood the question.edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not clear about exactly what `opt?` is doing on its own, nor why `opt?.isEmpty` is not the same as `(opt?)!.isEmpty`. I see how optional chaining is explained in the documentation as well as how `nil` is handled; none of that needs to be a part of the answer.

Comment: `opt?` is nothing in its own.`var o1 = opt?` is doing nothing just returning same value.It is same as `(opt?)`.Now to unwwrap you need single `!` operator.

Comment: But `opt?` is not, in general, "nothing on its own". If `opt` `String!` instead of `String?`, `opt?` and `opt` are not the same.

Comment: opt? always return optional see optional chaining so if opt:String! is implicit optional but when you use opt? it return optional(explicit optional).

Comment: See additional note above. This is not about the difference between `String?` and `opt?` (that's clear) nor about the intended functionality of optional chaining.