# Cannot invoke to != nil in xcode 6.1 generating error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6.1

Cannot invoke to != nil in xcode 6.1 generating error

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {

    if(elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item"){
        if ftitle != nil{
        elements.setObject(self.ftitle, forKey: "title")
        }
        if link != nil {
            elements.setObject(self.link, forKey: "link")
        }
        if fdescription  != nil{
        elements.setObject(self.fdescription, forKey: "description")
        }

        feeds.addObject(elements)
    }
}
```

Comment: i m new to ios please help != nil is not working what should i do

Comment: Please consider adding the whole stack trace to your question.

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of ftitle, link and fdescription?

Answer (score 1):

If `ftitle`, `link` and `fdescription` are not *Optional* you cannot compare them to `nil`.

```
var str1:String?
var str2:String = "a"

if str1 != nil{ } // OK

if str2 != nil{ } // ERROR (Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument ....)
```

---

See explanation here [What is an optional value in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

I think `ftitle` , `link` and `fdescription` are not optionals.

If I assume `ftitle` is a String,

I would declare it as

```
var ftitle  : String?
```

Then you can check `!= nil` or you can you can unwrap it like

```
if let temp = ftitle{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-optional values cannot be compared to nil because they cannot be nil that's the entire idea behind optional and non-optional,

if you think that at any place your variable may or may not hold any value then you should declare your variable as optional and not non-optional.

Below code sample shows an example of optional string

```
var myOptionalStringType:String? = "NSDumb"

if (myOptionalStringType != nil) {
println("It's not nil")
}else{
println("its nil")
}
```

I suggest reading [this blog on optional type](http://lithium3141.com/blog/2014/06/19/learning-swift-optional-types/) that would help you out on when you should use optional types.