# What is meant By Optional Value?

Tags: ios, iphone

> ***How to use Optional Value in Swift Language?***

Comment: You should have a look at Apple's The Swift Programming Language if you don't understand any swift concepts.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Optional Value is unwrapped Value of variable,which means the value of that variable can be nil.

Answer (score -1):

Optional value in Swift is similar to messaging nil in Objective-C, but in a way that works for any type, and that can be checked for success or failure.