# Cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, *: NSString?)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I just updated my Xcode to 6.3.1 The problem is my Facebook integration suddenly generate weird errors. Before this (Swift 1.1 and Xcode 6.2) no issue at all.

Error message 1

> /Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/AppDelegate.swift:33:41: Cannot
>   invoke 'handleOpenURL' with an argument list of type '(NSURL,
>   sourceApplication: NSString?)'

Error message 2

> /Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/AppDelegate.swift:32:10:
>   Objective-C method 'application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:'
>   provided by method
>   'application(*:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)' conflicts with
>   optional requirement method
>   'application(*:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)' in protocol
>   'UIApplicationDelegate'

My code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool { //error message 1 here
        var wasHandled:Bool = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) //error message 2 here
        return wasHandled
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @airspeed . I already fully understand about the optional. So what I do right now is like this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool { //error message 1 here
        var wasHandled:Bool = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!) //error message 2 here
        return wasHandled
    }
```

It works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your function declaration, `sourceApplication` is an optional:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, 
        openURL url: NSURL, 
        sourceApplication: NSString?,     // note, NSString? so optional
        annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
```

but in the call to `FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication)`, `sourceApplication` is `NSString`, i.e. non-optional.

You need to unwrap the input `sourceApplication` value, either with `if-let`, or default it with `??` i.e. `FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication ?? "defaultAppName")`, or even better if you control the declaration of the `application` func, have it not be optional in the first place.

Comment: Learn about optionals.  You won’t be able to write swift code without knowing this, telling you how to solve this specific problem isn’t going to help.  Start  with the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).  You can also try reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29717210/3925941) for some basic techniques.