# Swift: how to optionally pass function as parameter and invoke the function?

Tags: ios, swift

How can you optionally pass in a function to another function? Concretely, assume functionA accepts as a parameter functionB. If functionB is not nil, how can you execute functionB inside of functionA?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hard to see what's hard about this, so maybe this isn't what you mean, as it seems so trivially obvious; but anyway, here goes:

```
func optionalFunctionExpecter(f:(()->())?) {
    f?()
}
```

Here's how to call it with an actual function:

```
func g() {
    println("okay")
}
optionalFunctionExpecter(g)
```

Or, calling it with an actual anonymous function:

```
optionalFunctionExpecter { println("okay2") }
```

Here's how to call it with `nil`:

```
optionalFunctionExpecter(nil)
```

Observe that in my implementation of `optionalFunctionExpecter`, when called with `nil`, nothing will happen: we won't call `f`, we won't crash, we won't do anything. If you need to *know* that `nil` was passed, you can readily find out: just ask, in `optionalFunctionExpecter`, whether `f == nil` and proceed on that basis as desired. For more flexibility, we could rewrite like this:

```
func optionalFunctionExpecter(f:(()->())?) {
    if let f = f {
        f()
    } else {
        // ... nil was passed, respond to that fact ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What if someone passes nil into optionalFunctionExpecter? In other words, sometimes a function will get passed, and other times, no function gets passed. Doesn't "f?()" throw an exception if the function is nil?

Comment: No – `f?()` is optional chaining (in a similar fashion to `maybeObj?.property` or `maybeArray?[0]`.  If will check if `f` is `nil`, and if not, execute it.  The return value will be wrapped in an optional, and be `nil` if `f` was `nil` and not executed.

Comment: @Crashalot check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/29717211/3925941 for a long list of optional-handling techniques

Comment: @Crashalot added an alternative implementation that lets you respond consciously to nil being passed in, if desired

Comment: @matt, thanks so much! do you happen to be familiar with spritekit btw?

Comment: May I ask, where do I find this in the Swift documentation? It may seem trivial, but to someone learning the language, it might not be! =]

Comment: @Relequestual "where do I find this" What is "this"? What part is hard or surprising? Functions as parameters? Optionals? Give me some idea what you need to know.

Comment: @matt You said "Hard to see what's hard about this..." so I'm realting to the same "this". The subject of this question this. More specifically however, where do I find `(f:(()->())?)` explained in the documentation, or how did you gleam such from which documentation?

Comment: @Relequestual I'm happy to help if you will be specific. Which part of `f:(()->())?` do you need explanation for?

Comment: Thanks @matt. I understand what the `f:` part does, but I'm not sure on my understanding on the rest. Is it saying, this function should take a function which returns a function? if that is the case, and I'm reading it right, where do I find this in the Swift documentation?

Comment: @Relequestual it says that the parameter `f` is a function taking no parameters and returning no value, wrapped up in an Optional — which is what the OP asked for. Here's the discussion of functions as parameters from my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_as_value

Comment: Awesome thankyou! I'll be sure to check out your book! =]