# Swift: How to convert String to UInt?

Tags: string, swift, type-conversion, uint

According to [Swift - Converting String to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/swift-converting-string-to-int), there's a `String` method `toInt()`.

But, there's no `toUInt()` method. So, how to convert a `String` to a `Uint`?

Comment: for additional detail swift 2.x , String does not contain toInt()

Comment: @Eric D.. Thanks for clarifying on tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update for Swift 2/Xcode 7:**

As of Swift 2, all integer types have a (failable) constructor

```
init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)
```

which replaces the `toInt()` method of `String`, so no custom
code is needed anymore for this task:

```
print(UInt("1234")) // Optional(1234)
// This is UInt.max on a 64-bit platform:
print(UInt("18446744073709551615")) // Optional(18446744073709551615)
print(UInt("18446744073709551616")) // nil (overflow)
print(UInt("1234x")) // nil (invalid character)
print(UInt("-12")) // nil (invalid character)
```

---

**Old answer for Swift 1.x:**

This looks a bit complicated, but should work for all numbers in the
full range of `UInt`, and detect all possible errors correctly
(such as overflow or trailing invalid characters):

```
extension String {
    func toUInt() -> UInt? {
        if contains(self, "-") {
            return nil
        }
        return self.withCString { cptr -> UInt? in
            var endPtr : UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = nil
            errno = 0
            let result = strtoul(cptr, &endPtr, 10)
            if errno != 0 || endPtr.memory != 0 {
                return nil
            } else {
                return result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Remarks:**

- The BSD library function [`strtoul`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strtoul.3.html) is used for the conversion.
  The `endPtr` is set to first "invalid character" in the input string,
  therefore `endPtr.memory == 0` must be hold if *all* characters
  could be converted.
  In the case of a conversion error, the global `errno` variable is set
  to a non-zero value (e.g. `ERANGE` for an overflow).
- The test for a minus sign is necessary because `strtoul()` accepts
  negative numbers (which are converted to the unsigned number with the
  same bit pattern).
- A Swift string is converted to a C string "behind the scenes" when
  passed to a function taking a `char *` parameter, so one could be
  tempted to call `strtoul(self, &endPtr, 0)` (which is what I did in
  the first version of this answer). The problem is that the automatically
  created C string is only temporary and can already be invalid when
  `strtoul()` returns, so that `endPtr` does not point to a 
  character in the input string anymore. This happened when I tested the code in the Playground. With `self.withCString { ... }`, this problem does not occur because the C string is valid throughout the execution
  of the closure.

Some tests:

```
println("1234".toUInt()) // Optional(1234)
// This is UInt.max on a 64-bit platform:
println("18446744073709551615".toUInt()) // Optional(18446744073709551615)
println("18446744073709551616".toUInt()) // nil (overflow)
println("1234x".toUInt()) // nil (invalid character)
println("-12".toUInt()) // nil (invalid character)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if the downvoter left an explaining comment.

Comment: how to convert `0xff0000` string to UInt?

Comment: @TomSawyer easy :-) let str = "0xff0000"; let p = UInt(String(str.characters.dropFirst(2)),radix: 16) // Optional(16711680)

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in a safer solution similar to:

```
let uIntString = "4"
let nonUIntString = "foo"

extension String {
    func toUInt() -> UInt? {
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: self)
        var u: UInt64 = 0
        if scanner.scanUnsignedLongLong(&u)  && scanner.atEnd {
            return UInt(u)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

uIntString.toUInt()     // Optional(4)
nonUIntString.toUInt()  // nil
```

Hope this helps

// Edited following @Martin R. suggestion

Comment: One concern here is that this will accept garbage on the end of the string, which doesn’t match the behaviour of the similar `toInt()` function i.e. `"4blah".toInt()` returns `nil` but `"4blah".toUInt()` returns `4`

Comment: ... That can easily be solved by adding the test `&& scanner.atEnd`. Another problem is that *overflow* is not detected.

Comment: @Martin R. The _overflow_ detection could be added scanning for a `Decimal` and then doing the appropriate checks. This quick solution could work for the majority of common cases, avoiding `!` crashes.

Comment: huh, TIL `NSScanner` silently swallows overflows, bit rude of it.

Answer (score 3):

Please, for the love of not crashing, don’t use `!` to do this.

It’s easy to tack a `map` on the end of `toInt` to convert it to an optional `UInt`:

```
let str = "4"
let myUInt = str.toInt().flatMap { $0 < 0 ? nil : UInt($0) }
```

then use [the usual unwrapping techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717505/3925941) on `myUInt`.

And if you find yourself doing this a lot:

```
extension String {
    func toUInt() -> UInt? {
        return self.toInt().flatMap { $0 < 0 ? nil : UInt($0) }
    }
}

let str = "-4"
if let myUInt = str.toUInt() {
    println("yay, \(myUInt)")
}
else {
    println("nuh-uh")
}
```

edit: as @MartinR points out, while safe, this doesn’t extract the full range of possible values for a `UInt` that `Int` doesn’t cover, see the other two answers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be flatMap() in the first one there?

Comment: This (as well as the previous two answers) will not work if the number is outside the range of  a *signed* integer.

Comment: oops yes you’re absolutely correct, I pulled the extra check up to the first example but forgot to amend the map

Comment: @MartinR excellent point, in which case yes, @Matteo’s `NSScanner` solution is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Use Forced Unwrapping or Optional Binding to make sure the string can be converted to UInt.
eg:

```
let string = "123"
let number = UInt(string) //here number is of type *optional UInt*

//Forced Unwrapping

if number != nil {
  //converted to type UInt
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just use UInt's init:

```
let someString = "4"

UInt(someString.toInt()!) // 4
```

Comment: This generates a __runtime exception__ if conversion fails