# How to convert a String to UInt32 in Swift

Tags: string, swift, uint32

```
let temp: String = "0xffeeffff"
```

How to convert above String to UInt32, because I need to store it in the bitmap which only accept UInt32

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382414/swift-how-to-convert-string-to-uint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to Uint32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573609/convert-string-to-uint32)

Comment: so? you should select an answer to let people know what worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove "0x" from your string to convert it to UInt32:

```
let temp   = "0xffeeffff"
let result = UInt32(String(temp.characters.dropFirst(2)), radix: 16)
```

Comment: thank you for your replying. But when I pass the result to the bitmapData[offset], you have to pass like "0xffeeffff" with "0x"

Comment: @shixiaoz i've updated my answer. the "0x" is now removed while converting, but leaving `temp` as it is.

Comment: @DevranCosmoUenal String("0xffeeffff".characters.suffix(8))

Comment: @LeoDabus I was not sure if `temp` could also be `0xff` so I took the search-and-replace way.

Comment: @LeoDabus `String("0xff".characters.suffix(8))` results `0xff`. `String(temp.characters.dropFirst(2))` would work.

Comment: but it would've to start with 0x

Comment: can also check if it hasPrefix("0x") before dropping them

Answer (score 2):

hope this is help you...

```
extension String {
func toUInt() -> UInt? {
    if contains(self, "-") {
        return nil
    }
    return self.withCString { cptr -> UInt? in
        var endPtr : UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = nil
        errno = 0
        let result = strtoul(cptr, &endPtr, 10)
        if errno != 0 || endPtr.memory != 0 {
            return nil
        } else {
            return result
        }
    }
}
}
```