# Nicer syntax for ternary with a let?

Tags: swift

Is there a nicer way to do the assignment to DEF in the following example?  I want to convert type A to Type B, but still preserve the nil possibility whenever I can.

Can't seem to stumble into a better way of doing this, however.  Suggestions?

```
class ABC {

  var DEF: Int?

  func X (someValue: Int8?) {
    DEF = someValue != nil ? Int(someValue) : nil
  }
}
```

Comment: you might find [this list of ways to handle optionals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil/29717211#29717211) useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 1:

```
class ABC {

  var DEF: Int?

  func X (someValue: Int8?) {
    DEF = someValue.map{Int($0)}
  }
}
```

Swift 2:

```
class ABC {

  var DEF: Int?

  func X (someValue: Int8?) {
    DEF = someValue.map(Int.init)
  }
}
```

`map()` takes an optional, unwraps it, and applies a function to it. If the optional resolves to nil, `map()` returns nil.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing optional `map`:

```
var i: Int? = 2
let j = i.map { $0 * 2 }  // j = .Some(4)
i = nil
let k = i.map { $0 * 2 }  // k = nil
```

Think of this map like array or other collection map, where optionals are collections that have either zero (`nil`) or one (non-`nil`) element.

Note, if the operation you want to perform itself returns an optional, you need `flatMap` to avoid getting a double-optional:

```
let s: String? = "2"
let i = s.map { Int($0) }      // i will be an Int??
let j = s.flatMap { Int($0) }  // flattens to Int?
```