# How to guard initialization of property that may fail

Tags: swift, option-type

My class has a property of type `NSURL` that is initialized from a string. The string is known at compile time.

For the class to operate appropriately, it *must* be set to its intended value *at initialization* (**not later**), so there is no point in defining it as an optional (implicitly unwrapped or otherwise):

```
class TestClass: NSObject {

    private let myURL:NSURL

    ...
```

Assuming that `NSURL(string:)` (which returns `NSURL?`) will never fail if passed a valid URL string that is known at compile time, I can do something like this:

```
    override init() {

        myURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!

        super.init()
    }
```

However, I somehow **don't feel comfortable around the forced unwrapping** and would like to guard the URL initialization somehow. If I try this:

```
    guard myURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com") else {
        fatalError()
    }
```

> Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!'
>   or '?'?

(Note: there's no way to add a `!` or `?` anywhere the code above that will fix the error. Conditional unwrapping only happens with `guard let...` `guard var...`, and `myURL` is already defined)

I understand why this fails: Even a successful call to `NSURL(string:)` is returning the (valid) `NSURL` *wrapped* inside an optional `NSURL?`, so I still need to unwrap it somehow before assigning to `myURL` (which is non-optional, hence not compatible for assignment *as-is*).

I can get around this by using an intermediate variable:

```
    guard let theURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com") else {
        fatalError()
    }

    myURL = theURL
```

...but this is obviously not elegant at all.

**What should I do?**

Comment: If you want to use optional binding in this situation, there is no alternative except to use the extra variable. I think using an `if let` statement might be a bit more elegant, as it confines the extra variable to the scope of the `if` block.

Comment: Also, if you're not concerned with dealing with an error, then you could use the nil coalescing operator: `myURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com") ?? NSURL()`.

Comment: If you expect that NSURL(string:) does not fail and you want your program to abort if it does (unexpectedly), then it makes no difference if you use forced unwrapping or guard+fatalError.

Comment: About unwrapping directly into properties, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271241/guard-when-setting-multiple-class-properties-in-swift-2.

Comment: "You can’t unwrap into existing variables. Instead, you have to unwrap, then assign". I guess that settles it.

Comment: I'm seriously considering marking my question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Thank you @LeoDabus, I fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** Another approach, that doesn't use `guard`, would be to use a `switch`, as optionals map to the `Optional` enum:

```
init?() {
    switch URL(string: "http://www.google.com") {
    case .none:
        myURL = NSURL()
        return nil
    case let .some(url):
        myURL = url
    }
}
```

although you'd still get a `url` local variable.

---

**Original answer**

You can declare your initializer as a failable one and return `nil` in case the url string parsing fails, instead of throwing a fatal error. This will make it more clear to clients your the class that the initializer might fail at some point. You still won't get rid of the `guard`, though.

```
init?() {

    guard let url = URL(string: "http:www.google.com") else {
        // need to set a dummy value due to a limitation of the Swift compiler
        myURL = URL()
        return nil
    }
    myURL = url

}
```

This add a little complexity on the caller side, as it will need to check if the object creation succeeded, but it's the recommended pattern in case the object initializer can fail constructing the object. You'd also need to give up the `NSObject` inheritance as you cannot override the `init` with a failable version (`init?`).

You can find out more details about failable initializers on the [Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17), [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID224), or this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495586/best-practice-to-implement-a-failable-initializer-in-swift).

Comment: or keep the inheritance and add to the failable initializer a parameter, for example the url string: `init?(url: String) {...}`

Comment: I already know that code (it's in my question). This part: `// need to set a dummy value due to a limitation of the Swift compiler`, I guess this is the (negative) answer to my question?

Comment: So, there's no `guard`ing without an intermediate variable?

Comment: I don't think so, you need to have a `let` declaration to unbind, which creates a local constant, see also Martin R's comment

Comment: @NicolasMiari I added a `switch`-based solution to my answer, maybe you'll like that better then the `guard` one :)

Comment: Interesting. I'm not looking for a failable initializer, but the "switch case none:" is something I didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasMiari optionals are mapped by the compiler to the `Optional` enum, this is why you can use the `switch` statement

Comment: Requiring a dummy value for properties when returning nil in an initializer is a compiler bug. I believe it has been fixed in the next release of Swift.