# Trying to convert a hexadecimal text to a decimal in swift, but getting "Optional([num])" output

Tags: ios, swift, hex, uitextview

I am trying to convert a hexadecimal number to a decimal number. The user inputs a hexadecimal in a textview, on text edit action the decimal textview outputs the conversion. I am getting a strange behavior where the decimal textview is displaying "Optional[num]" IE "Optional(9) if I type in 9. Here is the hexadecimal text action listener:

```
@IBAction func inputHex(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(Int(hexText.text!) != nil){
            inputNumberText = hexText.text!

            let st3 = Int(inputNumberText, radix: 16)
            decText.text = String(st3)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let st3 = Int(inputNumberText, radix: 16)
```

calls the "failable initializer"

```
init?(_ text: String, radix radix: Int = default)
```

of `struct Int`, and that is failable for a good reason: It returns `nil`
if the string is not a valid number representation in the given base.
For example

```
Int("12XYZ", radix: 16)
Int("789", radix: 8)
```

would return `nil`. So `st3` is an optional, and therefore `String(st3)`
is the string "Optional(...)".

But note that there are more issues with your code:

- Don't use `AnyObject` parameters in action methods. Always use the
  real type (in this case: `UITextField`)  for better type checking.
  Xcode has an option for that when you connect the action.
- Never unwrap forcefully. Use optional binding instead.
- Comparing against `nil` can and should be avoided in almost all
  cases.

With regard to the last two points, compare [When should I compare an optional value to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil).

In your case

```
if (Int(hexText.text!) != nil)
```

is even *wrong* because it rejects valid hexadecimal strings like "ABCD".

This is how your action method could look like:

```
@IBAction func inputHex(sender: UITextField) {
    if let text = sender.text,
        let number = Int(text, radix: 16) {
        decText.text = String(number)
    }
}
```

Both `let text = ...` and `let number = ...` are *optional bindings*
in the context of the if-statement, and the if-block is only executed
if both bindings succeed.