# Swift shorthand null check

Tags: swift, syntax

What is the equivalent in Swift of objc's:

```
NSObject* x = nil;
if(x) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Also what is the equivalent of:

```
if(!x) return;
```

In swift you must use {} for some reason?

Comment: Have a look at [When should I compare an optional value to nil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil).

Comment: *"In swift you must use {} for some reason?"* – That is covered in the chapter "A Swift Tour" very early in the Swift book.

Comment: Sorry Martin, I'm asking whether or not there is a shorthand way to say if(nil == nil) return;
Most other languages allow one liners.

Comment: Swift allows one-liners as well but it requires also the braces after an `if` statement. Just add `!= nil` and the braces and you're done. PS: And remove the trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in swift you should always use curly braces with `if` operator:

```
var x: NSObject? // value of Optional type set to nil automatically
if let x = x {
    //do stuff
}
```

here you used optional binding, you declared local variable `x` inside `if` scope. In start of function also `guard` keyword is useful:

```
guard let x = x else {return}
//do stuff
```

If you for some reason wish to use unwrapped original variable (thought you always have access to properties with `self` keyword, `self.x` - property, `x` - local scope variable), you should just compare it to nil:

```
if x != nil {
    //do stuff
}
```

or

```
if x == nil {return}
```