# How to combine multiple nullable NSPredicates?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

For eg, Something like:

```
    var finalPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "")

    if (screen != nil) {
        screenPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "screen = %@", screen!)
        finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [screenPredicate!])
    }

    if (feature != nil) {
        featurePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "feature = %@", feature!)
        finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [finalPredicate, featurePredicate!])
    }

    if (shouldDisplayPredicate != nil) {
        shouldDisplayPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "shouldDisplay = %@", shouldDisplay!)
        finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [finalPredicate, shouldDisplayPredicate!])
    }
    if (hasDisplayed != nil) {
        displayPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "hasDisplayed = %@", hasDisplayed!)
        finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [finalPredicate, displayPredicate!])
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this where the predicates could be null or not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should avoid the forced unwrapping and replace

```
if screen != nil {
    // ... add predicate for `screen!` ...
}
```

by an optional binding:

```
if let screenValue = screen {
    // ... add predicate for `screenValue` ...
}
```

Compare [When should I compare an optional value to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil) for a good overview of that topic.
The same can be achieved more compactly using the `map()` method
of `Optional`:

```
screen.map { /* ... add predicate for `$0` ... }
```

The closure is called only if `screen != nil`, and then `$0` inside
the closure is the unwrapped value.

Second, it is simpler to fill an array with all required predicates
first, and create the compound predicate only once.
This also allows you to check if any search attribute was set at all.

Your code then becomes

```
var predicates: [NSPredicate] = []
if let screenValue = screen {
    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "screen = %@", screenValue))
}
if let featureValue = feature {
    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "feature = %@", featureValue))
}
// ... other search attributes ...
if !predicates.isEmpty {
    let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates)
}
```

or

```
var predicates: [NSPredicate] = []
screen.map { predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "screen = %@", $0)) }
feature.map { predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "feature = %@", $0)) }
// ... other search attributes ...
if !predicates.isEmpty {
    let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates)
}
```

Comment: The map option looks neat though a bit hard to read for the untrained (in swift) eye.

Comment: @ofeida: That's why I presented both :)