# Unwrapping optionals with just `let`

Tags: swift, option-type

Can someone help me understand the following code expression, how would you read it?

```
let myVar = (someOptional != nil) ? someOptional! : ""
```

If someOptional is not nil unwrap it? if this is correct, what does do the `?` and the `:""` in the expression?

I have always unwrapped my optionals with `if let`s but and I'm not sure how the above code reads.

Here is a more concrete real code example that shows how it is used...

```
let currentZipCode = (placemark.postalCode != nil) ? placemark.postalCode! : ""
```

Comment: Look up “ternary conditional operator” in the Swift docs ...

Comment: Also, this is poor usage of ternary operator, [`nil coalescing` operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html) suits here better.

Comment: there is a quicker way to do this -> `let myVar = someOptional ?? ""` this means, if someOptional is not nil, use the unwrapped content but if it is nil, use "". --- just fyi

Comment: Thank you all for the good information. I will read more about ternary conditional operator and coalescing operator. @user28434 - would you mind elaborating a little more on why it is a poor usage in this case?

Comment: Using `nil coalescing operator` here is way more cleaner and shorter, less repetitions. Also, `??` operator will evaluate expression that is checked for `nil` only once, while that ad-hoc ternary operator will do it twice. If your `placemark.postalCode` causes some resource heavy calculations in the getter you will have them performed twice.

Comment: Also related: [When should I compare an optional value to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil)