# what's the meaning of optional binding in swift

Tags: ios, swift

without optional binding,we use optional like this,it seems tedious

```
func doSomething(str: String?)
{
    let v: String! = str
    if v != nil
    {
        // use v to do something
    }
}
```

with optional binding,it seems the `if let` doesn't do any thing to make it less tedious. **we still have a if statement to test before use it.**

```
func doSomething(str: String?)
{
    if let v = str
    {
        // use v to do something
    }
}
```

Is there any other examples can show some benefits to use optional bindings ?

Comment: Try optional binding of long optional chain. And variable used multiple times in the if statement. If you do so, you will get your all answers.

Comment: Quite a few [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+optional+binding) which might be useful

Comment: Compile-time check is more important benefit I believe

Comment: Please read the [section about Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) in the Language Guide

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [When should I compare an optional value to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29717210/1187415)

Comment: @dahiya_boy, would u say it more specificly? thanks! i don't see any need to use optional binding in optional chain

Comment: @ximmyxiao One answer is already available below which explains optional binding with optional chain. If you need further info and explanation other way, then let me know.

Comment: @dahiya_boy,thanks,seems the optional binds in optional chain saves lot of writing only ?

Comment: @ximmyxiao Yeah you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Advantages of the `Optional binding` over `If Statements and Forced Unwrapping`**:

- local variable which is not an optional and a shortcut when a structure is deeper than one level

Context:

**You have three techniques to work with an optionals:**

- Optional binding
- If statements and forced unwrapping
- Optional chaining

**Optional binding**

> You use optional binding to find out whether an optional contains a
>   value, and if so, to make that value available as a temporary constant
>   or variable. Optional binding can be used with if and while statements
>   to check for a value inside an optional, and to extract that value
>   into a constant or variable, as part of a single action.

**If Statements and Forced Unwrapping**

> You can use an if statement to find out whether an optional contains a
>   value by comparing the optional against nil. You perform this
>   comparison with the “equal to” operator (==) or the “not equal to”
>   operator (!=).

**Optional chaining**

> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties,
>   methods, and subscripts on an optional that might currently be nil. If
>   the optional contains a value, the property, method, or subscript call
>   succeeds; if the optional is nil, the property, method, or subscript
>   call returns nil. Multiple queries can be chained together, and the
>   entire chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is nil.

[source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

---

```
struct Computer {
    let keyboard: Keyboard?
}

struct Keyboard {
    let battery: Battery?
}

struct Battery {
    let price: Int?
}

let appleComputer: Computer? = Computer(keyboard: Keyboard(battery: Battery(price: 10)))

func getBatteryPriceWithOptionalBinding() -> Int {
    if let computer = appleComputer {
        if let keyboard = computer.keyboard {
            if let battery = keyboard.battery {
                if let batteryPrice = battery.price {
                    print(batteryPrice)
                    return batteryPrice
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
}

func getBatteryPriceWithIfStatementsAndForcedUnwrapping() -> Int {
    if appleComputer != nil {
        if appleComputer!.keyboard != nil {
            if appleComputer!.keyboard!.battery != nil {
                if appleComputer!.keyboard!.battery!.price != nil {
                    print(appleComputer!.keyboard!.battery!.price!)
                    return appleComputer!.keyboard!.battery!.price!
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
}

func getBatteryPriceWithOptionalChainingAndForcedUnwrapping() -> Int {
    if appleComputer?.keyboard?.battery?.price != nil {
        print(appleComputer!.keyboard!.battery!.price!)
        return appleComputer!.keyboard!.battery!.price!
    }
    return 0
}

func getBatteryPriceWithOptionalChainingAndOptionalBinding() -> Int {
    if let price = appleComputer?.keyboard?.battery?.price {
        print(price)
        return price
    }
    return 0
}

func getBatteryPriceWithOptionalChainingAndNilCoalescing() -> Int {
    print(appleComputer?.keyboard?.battery?.price ?? 0)
    return appleComputer?.keyboard?.battery?.price ?? 0
}
```

Comment: Using optional binding has one major advantage. You don't need to unwrap the binded variable. That makes code easier to write.

Comment: thanks @Adobels,seems the  optional chain with nil coalesce are the most recommended way to work with optional

Comment: @ximmyxiao yes.

Comment: Returning zero instead of optional Int for price is pointless. zero it is not a valid value for price if any object in the chain is nil `var appleKeyboardBatteryPrice: Int? { appleComputer?.keyboard?.battery?.price
}`