# Swift, Convert String To Double Error

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, double

i wrote a code to convert string to double but gives error :

**Cannot convert the expression's type 'Double' to type 'NSString'**

and my code is :

```
var first = previewLable.text
var second = label1.text

var number1: Double = (first as NSString).doubleValue
var number2: Double = (second as NSString).doubleValue
```

what i have to do to fix this error ???

*Thanks*

Comment: Please use "label", not "lable".

Comment: oops :D , Sorry , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to unwrap it like this:

```
var number1: Double = (first! as NSString).doubleValue
var number2: Double = (second! as NSString).doubleValue
```

Or you can use this way which is safe:

```
if let first = previewLable.text, second = lable1.text{
    var number1: Double = (first as NSString).doubleValue
    var number2: Double = (second as NSString).doubleValue
}
```

And for info about `?` and `!` read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift).

Answer (score 13):

Also if you're in Swift 2 you can use

```
Double("3.141592")
```

which gives an Optional Double, depending on whether it could be parsed

```
Double("hi")
```

would give `nil`