# Checking if text fields are empty cause error in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift2

I am trying to check if a textbox has no value.

When I do this:

```
if(userEmail?.isEmpty || userPassword?.isEmpty || userPasswordRepeat?.isEmpty)
```

I get the following error
[image]

I tried adding "?" before the ".isEmpty" but the error won't go away
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It's in the error message: Optional value not unwrapped. Use `!` to unwrap a value and read up on [optional values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Comment: @EICaptain Is there a difference between `textfield.text` and `textfield.stringValue`?

Comment: @EICaptain I'm asking. I'm used to using `stringValue`

Comment: @Arc676 `stringValue` property is not a member of textfiled when your develop app for iPhone or iPad...is available in mac app

Comment: This is a screenshot with the variables too. http://ge.tt/3NeaYbP2/v/0?c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
if txtEmail.text?.isEmpty == true || txtPassword.text?.isEmpty == true || txtRePassword.text?.isEmpty == true{
        print("true")
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. This is the error message I recieve. http://ge.tt/8F7FbbP2/v/0?c

Comment: glad it helps...happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If interested also in positive case, the following is an alternative solution for **Swift 2**:

```
let email = self.txtEmail.text where !email.isEmpty, let password = self.txtPassword.text where !password.isEmpty {
    //all fields are not nil && not empty
}else{
    //some field is nil or empty
}
```