# Swift with Core Data getting an "Optional("")" on the strings i am fetching?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is it normal to get an extra "Optional("")" on the strings i am fetching in Core Data?

Here is the code

```
bowtie.name = "My bow tie"
bowtie.lastWorn = NSDate()
```

And this is what i am getting in the xcode output log.

Name: Optional("My bow tie"), Worn: Optional(2015-11-08 14:23:11 +0000)

Is there a way to get rid of the Optional("") thing?

Comment: The app will crash @kostek!

Comment: You're right, if you force unwrap an optional that is nil, the app will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you force unwrap an `Optional` (using `!`) a kitten **dies**.

There are several safe ways of unwrapping an `Optional` such as using `if let` or `flatMap` (even though it's not a real `flatMap`).

In several cases you can use Optional Chaining so you don't have to deal with `Optional`s before you actually have to. The null coalescing operator (`??`) is also pretty useful.

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026093/2305521) answer is extremely helpful, you should definitely check it out.

If you want to fully understand the concept of `Optional`s take a look at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

In that specific case, though, I'd recommend using something like `let fetchedName = bowtie.name ?? ""` (or any other fallback string that makes sense for your problem).
When you force unwrap and for some bizarre reason the value is `nil` the app **will crash**. Nobody likes crashes, right?