# In Swift, do I need to force unwrapping a variable after I create an instance for it?

Tags: swift, swift2

Please see the code below:

```
class myViewMgr {
    var myView: UIView?

    func create() {
        myView = UIView()
        myView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        myView!...
        myView!...
    }
}
```

I have a class and a variable `myView` which might be empty. Inside `create()`, I create an instance for it and start using it. And I have to force unwrapping `myView` in the following code.

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong in some general Swift concept? Any advise to help me and correct me is appreciated.

Comment: You can force unwrapping If you make sure it not null at time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would work around it by doing

```
let view = UIView()
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
...
myView = view
```

But if you do use the attribute, then yes, you will need to force unwrap it every single time.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, if you are sure that myView is never going to be nil once you invoke create() on it, it is better to declare myView as an implicitely unwrapped variable:

```
var myView: UIView!
```

And then after the Create() called, you can use myView as any other variable without needing to forced unwrapping etc.

Comment: no, I can't. I actually check if myView is nil in the beginning of create()

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this way because you declare a type called "Optional UIView". That's why you always need to use `!` to unwrap it. If you are sure that `view` is always there. You can just declare it as `UIView`. Then, it's just like how you use it in other normal programming language.

We have great explanation in this platform. You should make decision after understand what it actually is: [What is an optional value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)