# Is any function in swift similar to R.java in Android?

Tags: android, ios, swift, r.java-file

I am a beginner in iOS and swift.

I used to write Android and I think the R.java is a good idea to manage ids, drawables, strings and other resources.
So I'm surprised that iOS does't provide a good function to access resources.

If I want to get a Image from assets, I call `UIImage(named: "img_name")`, but I don't think this is the best way to access `img_name`, I may use a wrong name and I can't get the image.

I found some open source project like [Shark](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/Shark) and [SwiftGen](https://github.com/AliSoftware/SwiftGen), but `Shark` only support images and `SwiftGen` it seems need to run a command not automatically.

Do you have any better solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a open source project [R.swift-plugin](https://github.com/azurechen/R.swift-plugin) it provides features as you mentioned. You just need to install the Xcode Plugin via [Alcatraz](http://Alcatraz.io) and search `R.swift`

The plugin will automatically generate a resource file to manage your images, localizable strings and colors, and you can access them like using R.java

Usage:

[image]

Sincerely recommend you to try it. And feel free to give me any suggestion to improve it :)

Comment: It looks definitely what I want! But just supports strings, images, colors. Anyway I will try it.

Comment: Yes, I think the strings, images and colors should be the most common resources.

Comment: But I plan to make it support id(reuseidentifier, segue), layout(nib), bool, dimen and integer later! I really hope this plugin will be helpful.

Comment: Be aware, that while this "R.swift-plugin" uses a very similar name, it is unrelated to the [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift) tool.

Answer (score 4):

- If you are using `InterfaceBuilder` (also called `Storyboard`, `xib`), there is no need to define id for each view. You can [bind](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html) outlets in code.
- If you want to retrieve views using their ids (like `R.java` as you asked), you can set tag to each view and manipulate them in code.
  [image]

Unlike AndroidStudio, Xcode will **not** generate any file.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    let labelView = self.view.viewWithTag(0) as? UILabel
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it only support ids and layouts right? Is there any function to manage images , colors or strings?

Comment: Add your images to `Assets` folder in Xcode. Usually, it's enough to add only 3x images to be appear and scale properly. `UIImage(named: "hello")` will retrieve image named `hello` from `Assets`.

Comment: Yes, but using the name of images to init may failed because of typo

Comment: @FindleyTyler Yes you're right. But, in Swift there is a special generic type called `Optional`. By default, all types and classes are nil "non-compatible". That means, you cannot assign `nil` as value and compiling code fails. `Optional` makes them assignable, so your app will not crash, unless you force to unwrap them. Here is more info. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24026093/3815843

Comment: Also, `UIImageView` has property `image` with type of `UIImage?` that means `Optional<UIImage>`. You can assign `nil` to `image` and the view will not render anything. So if you expect some image but you are not seeing anything, probably you made a typo

Answer (score 4):

There is no such function in Xcode itself, but there is an open source project that does just this: [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift)

It automatically updates the generated file and supports a lot of different resource types such as images, fonts, segues and more.

Comment: The steps of installation looks so complicate. But it seems a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can have *similar* functionality by using extensions and enums.

Using enums allows you to avoid typos and benefit from Xcode's autosuggest/autocomplete.

Example for UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {

    enum ImageId: String {
        // These are your images NAMES,
        // as in "SpriteMonster.jpg"
        case SpriteMonster, SpriteHero, BaseLandscape
    }

    convenience init!(id: ImageId) {
        self.init(named: id.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let monster = UIImage(id: .SpriteMonster)  // the "SpriteMonster.jpg" image
```

*For this example I'm force-unwrapping the convenience init, so be careful to actually have the image with the correct name in your bundle.*

For String:

```
extension String {

    enum StringId: String {
        case Welcome = "Welcome to the game!"
        case GameOver = "You loose! Game over!"
    }

    init(id: StringId) {
        self = id.rawValue
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let label = String(id: .Welcome) // "Welcome to the game!"
```

For fonts:

```
extension UIFont {

    enum FontId {
        case HelveticaNeueLarge
        case HelveticaNeueMedium
        case HelveticaNeueSmall

        func font() -> UIFont {
            switch self {
            case .HelveticaNeueLarge:
                return UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)!
            case .HelveticaNeueSmall:
                return UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12)!
            default:
                return UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14)!
            }
        }
    }

    class func get(id: FontId) -> UIFont {
        return id.font()
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let font = UIFont.get(.HelveticaNeueLarge) // <UICTFont: 0x7ffd38f09180> font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00pt
```

*These are only examples to demonstrate the concept, you can go much further with this.*

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Tuist](https://tuist.io) is has [`SwiftGen`](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen) [inside](https://docs.tuist.io/guides/resources). It allows to use it out of the box without adding third-party solutions. The disadvantage is that you have to run it every time when you change resource