# Error: Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'String'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
var firstName: String = "John Appleseed"
if let name = firstName {
    print ("Hello, \(name)")
}
```

String Error on second line: Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'String'

How to decide whether to use optional or non-optional variables?

Comment: The error says it all... you cannot use optional binding (`if let ...`) with a non-optional. Either change `String` to `String?`, or eliminate the optional binding altogether (depends whether this is just for demonstration or actual code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's consider what the `if let` construct means. When you write

```
if let name = firstName {
    print ("Hello, \(name)")
}
```

you tell Swift that you want to

1. Try unwrapping `firstName`
2. If the result of unwrapping is successful, assign the result of unwrapping to `name`
3. If the result of unwrapping is successful, print `"Hello, \(name)"`

In other words, this construct is for dealing with unwrapping of optional variables. However, variable `firstName` is *not* optional; there is nothing to unwrap, causing Swift to complain.

Answer (score 2):

```
var firstName: String? = "John Appleseed"
if let name = firstName {
print ("Hello, \(name)")
}
```

add `?` to make it optional.

check [answer in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift) to know where to use optional and what is actually it is

hope this will help :)

Comment: Note that this isn't great advice if this is actual production code... generally you should prefer non-optionals over optionals – therefore if you know the value of `firstName` when you define it, and you know it will always have a value, it should definitely be non-optional.