# What does the "Some" keyword in the Xcode console mean?

Tags: xcode, swift, lldb

Printing the description of an object yields lldb to use the keyword "Some" in front of the object's description (here I po an optional string):

```
(lldb) po someString
Optional<String>
 - Some: "Hello Jupiter"
```

What is the meaning of this keyword; why is it there?

Comment: Lookup the definition of `enum Optional`. It has two cases: `None` and ... `Some(Wrapped)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an optional value in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Comment: @JAL I approach the issue from a different, more pragmatic angle. I think it's a valid question, however I also agree that the answers to the linked question implicitly answers my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional) is an `enum` with two cases, [`none`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1640974-none), and [`some(wrapped)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1641449-some):

```
enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case some(Wrapped)
    case none
}
```

As you can see, the `Optional` either has a value of `Some`, with an associated value (the value the `Optional` wraps), or `None`. `Optional.None` is actually the meaning of `nil`.

In this case, the debugger is telling you that `someString` is an `Optional<String>` (a.k.a. `String?`), which has a value of `Optional.Some("Hello Jupiter")`. It's not `Optional.None`, thus it's not `nil`.

*Prior to Swift 3, these cases were capitalized, `Some` and `None`.*