# UIlabel text does not show "optional" word when setting optional text?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have been using optional a lot.I have declared a string variable as optional

```
var str: String?
```

Now i set some value in this variable as `str = "hello"`.Now if i print this optional without unwrapping then it print as

> Optional("hello")

But if i set text on the label as `self.label.text  = str` then it just display value as

> hello

Please explain why it does not show text as on label

> Optional("hello")

Comment: you should study the Opitinal :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift

Comment: Yeah! @aircraft gives you right link, first read it out.`Optional` word is not the part of the string . `Optional` just tells you that this `param` can be `nil` but its current value is `hello` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `text` property of `UILabel` is optional. `UILabel` is smart enough to check if the `text` property's value is set to `nil` or a non-nil value. If it's not `nil`, then it shows the properly unwrapped (and now non-optional) value.

Internally, I imagine the `drawRect` method of `UILabel` has code along the lines of the following:

```
if let str = self.text {
    // render the non-optional string value in "str"
} else {
    // show an empty label
}
```

Comment: so all the times I've see optional values for textField/textView/UILabel, they were all during my debugging?! And none were for when I was looking at the actual screen? Hard to believe :D

Answer (score 0):

I knew I've seen optionals printed in UILabel, UITextView, UITextField. Rmaddy's answer wasn't convincing.

It's very likely that there is an internal `if let else` so if the optional has a value then it will unwrap it and show. If not then it would show nothing.

However there's a catch!

```
let optionalString : String? = "Hello World"

label.text = "\(optionalString)" // Optional("Hello World")
label.text = optionalString // Hello World

let nilOptionalString : String?

label.text = "\(nilOptionalString)" // `nil` would be shown on the screen. 
label.text = nilOptionalString // no text or anything would be shown on the screen . It would be an empty label.
```

The reason is that once you do `"\(optionalVariable)"` then it would go through a string interpolation and once its a `String` and not `String?` then the result of the interpolation would be shown!