# How to display user input in an Alert? (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I'm roughly new to Swift programming, and was wondering if it is possible to display what the user inputted in the alert. This is what I have done:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

//MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
    nameTextField.delegate = self
}

//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    mealNameLabel.text = textField.text
    mealNameLabel.sizeToFit()
}

//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
    mealNameLabel.sizeToFit()
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello, \(mealNameLabel.text))", message: "Enjoy our new app and make sure you rate us in AppStore!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close Alert", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

When I run the program, it display "Hello, Optional((whatever I type here gets printed))". Why does the Optional thing appear with brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `mealNameLabel.text` is an [Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift). Optionals are declared with a `?` and the `text` value of `UILabel`s is of type `String?`. To access the underlying value, you have to unwrap it by using `!`, so your code would have to be

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello, \(mealNameLabel.text!))", message: "Enjoy our new app and make sure you rate us in AppStore!", preferredStyle: .alert)
```

However, if the value of the label is `nil`, your app would crash. See [the post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) for more info if your app crashes while unwrapping it.