# nil value handling in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to build an orders array in Swift. Sometimes the values that get filled in them are `nil`. This leads to an app crash. Ho do I handle this?

In the code below, I loop through orders and add them to the `orders` array:

```
var orders: [order] = []
//loop
orders[i] = order(dispatchNumber: "\
(myOrder.DispatchNumber!)",orderId: "\
(myOrder.OrderId!)", source: myOrder.SourceName! , sourceAddress1: myOrder.SourceAddress! , 
    sourceAddress2: myOrder.SourceCity! + ", " + myOrder.SourceState! +
 " " + myOrder.SourceZip! , destination: myOrder.DestinationName!, 
destinationAddress1:myOrder.DestinationAddress!, destinationAddress2:
myOrder.DestinationCity! + ", " + myOrder.DestinationState! + " " +
 myOrder.DestinationZip! , loads: "\(myOrder.LoadCount!)",
 loadsDelivered: "\(myOrder.LoadsDelivered!)",  tons: "\

(myOrder.TonsCount!)", price: "$" + "\(myOrder.PayRate!)", sourceDistance: myOrder.DistanceToSource!, onewayDistance: myOrder.OrderLegDistance!,  pickupStart: myOrder.PickupBy!, earliestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverStart!,latestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverBy!,product: myOrder.ProductName! , loadsRemaining: "\(thisLoadsRemaining)", truckType: myOrder.TruckType!, notes:
 myOrder.Notes!, isStarted: myOrder.IsStarted, isOnHold: myOrder.IsOnHold, payRateType: "\(myOrder.PayRateType!)", 
isStayOn: myOrder.IsStayOn, customerName: myOrder.CustomerName! )
```

Sometimes `myOrder.OrderLegDistance!` gets a `nil` value. How do I handle it?

Comment: Read something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift#24026093

Comment: Easy way to not crash: don't use the `!` operator.  How do you *want* to handle it?

Comment: Thank you appreciate the help :)

Comment: I checked for the nil value i.e.  var orderLegDistance = "--"
                        if myOrder.OrderLegDistance != nil {
                            orderLegDistance = myOrder.OrderLegDistance!
                        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safe bet would be to check for nil before unwrapping.

`var orderLegDistance = defaultValue
 if myOrder.OrderLegDistance != nil {
    orderLegDistance = myOrder.OrderLegDistance!
 }`

You can use the same kind of check to determine that you need to ignore the value of `myOrderLegDistance` if your logic demands that.

EDIT Adding some additional unwrapping options here:

```
if let legDistance = myOrder.OrderLegDistance {
    orderLegDistance = legDistance
}
```

Or, as mentioned in a comment below:

`orderLegDistance = myOrder.OrderLegDistance ?? defaultValue`

Comment: You could achieve the same with `var orderLegDistance = myOrder.OrderLeftDistance ?? defaultValue`.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally a bad idea to use implicitly unwrapping. **Always** handle the values safely.

Use `guard let` or `if let` to make sure the variables have a value when you work with them.

```
if let distance = orderLegDistance {
    print("\(distance)")
}

guard let distance = orderLegDistance else {
    print("Error: distance is empty")

    return
}
```

Moreover, you can define a default value by using `??`.

```
print("\(orderLegDistance ?? 0)") /*this will print 0 if orderLegDistance is empty*/
```

On a side note, always use **camelCase** variable names instead of **PascalCase**.

Comment: Thanks Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends of your business rules :

- If the `OrderLegDistant` is a mandatory value, you may want to 'forget' this order. In order to do that you can use a `guard` statement, to check all the mandatory params.
- If the`OrderLegDistant` is not mandatory, update your model to have this attribute as Optional, and remove the unwrap (`!`) from your constructor.

Comment: Thanks Appreciate the help :)