# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, null, option-type, skphysicsbody

I get the error for the line of code here:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    hero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 300))
}
```

I'm quite new to code and I am having trouble working out why I am getting this error.

Comment: Show the declaration of `hero`.

Comment: If it's failing at that line, then (a) `hero` is likely an implicitly unwrapped optional; and (b) it's `nil`. If this is the case, we then need to see not only how you declared it, but how you instantiated it, too.

Comment: Try to put hero?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 300)) if the problem is with hero. If it's not crashing tha't the case. If crashing there is something else.

Comment: @Arrabidas92 he would need also to change the declaration from IUO to optional

Comment: @LeoDabus what is IUO ?

Comment: @Arrabidas92 implicitly unwrapped optional

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah okay ! Yes you are right for the declaration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score -4):

physicsBody is probably nil, you can test for nil

```
if hero.physicsBody != nil {
    hero.physicsBody!.applyImplulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 300))
}else {
    //do whatever should be done when there is no physicsBody
}
```

there could be other issues but that is all that I can suggest without knowing more about your program

if you don't know what I mean by nil, I suggest reading more about optional data types [What is an optional value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I will definitely re-submerge myself into understanding optionals!

Comment: @Nemo This line it isn't the source of your problem. You are using optional chaining so your method applyImpulse  will never be called if physicsBody is nil. Your code would fail silently.