# save the text in a text field as a variable

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have been searching for an hour with no success so hope one of you will have pity.  I am using Xcode 9 and Swift 4.

```
textIt.text = name
```

Works perfectly and I have used it in my app but

```
name = textIt.text
```

brings up the error code:

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

All I want to do is to put some text from a variable into a field so the user can change it then I put the text back into the variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift Read this!

Answer (score 1):

In swift if a variable is optional and you want to set it to another you must use ! or ?? or If let You can try

```
let name =  textIt.text ?? ""
```

**OR**

```
 if let name =  textIt.text
 {
    print("name is : \(name)")
 }
```

**OR** but it may result in a crash if value is nil

```
 let name =  (textIt.text)!
```

Comment: None of this is needed. Simply do `let name = textIt.text!`. The `text` property is guaranteed never to return `nil`. It will return the empty string if there is no text.

Comment: @rmaddy it may have nil IBoutlet , also i demonstrate other options

Comment: @Sh_Khan All of the code in your answer will crash if the outlet is `nil`.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Because the `text` property is optional so it needs to be unwrapped. But since it never actually returns `nil`, it is safe to force-unwrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can track "name" variable when setting and getting textIt using something called Computer Property. This will allow you to tie your variable name and your text field.

```
var name:String? {

    get {
        return textIt.text
    }

    set {
        textIt.text = newValue
    }
}
```

When you set your name variable, textIt will automatically will be set. On the otherhand, when you get the name variable, i will get the value from textIt.

Since the name variable is optional you can use the following code to unwrap.

If let userName = name {

}