# I`m trying to get array from this evaluatejavascript to array

Tags: swift

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("getLangs()", completionHandler : { (value, error) in            
            print(value as Any)            
            })
```

result

```
Optional(["English","Հայերեն","Русский"])
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: i can get that array its only prints

Comment: And what do you want instead? You're calling `print`, what would you expect to happen? Common, please don't drop us one piece of information at a time, tell us the whole story.

Comment: Note that this method runs asynchronously. If you need to update your UI you need to do it inside the completion handler which runs on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use guard statement to unwrap optionals:

```
guard let array = value as? [String] else { return }
print(array)
```

**guard** creates the variable that can be accessed from outside its block. It is useful to unwrap a lot of Optionals.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift) for more details.

Comment: @ArturHarutyunyan can you try replacing `[String]` with [AnyObject]!!

Comment: @ArturHarutyunyan what didn't happen? Are you trying to say that you're not getting values?

Comment: nothing worked for me, anyway I changed my script and use it another way, just calling a func with parap.

Comment: @ArturHarutyunyan What was the problem, Why nothing worked, what do you want to be done? your questions are not clear and your comments are not clear as well.

Comment: I wana get array from js, that's all

Comment: @ArturHarutyunyan Yeah you told that already, What's going wrong when doing that?

Comment: nothing, just error, its not a string and its not a array

Comment: @ArturHarutyunyan Have you tried json serializing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if let array = value as? [String]{ print(array) }// now you've got the array
```

Comment: it means that this is not a string array (which is weird. from the description it looks like a string array)

Comment: I don't know what it was returning me))