# swift array optional to string

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and find out that Swift has optional string. I have issue unwrapping this optional. Here's the exmple:

```
for row in try database.prepare("SELECT name FROM airline WHERE carrier_id = \"\(text2)\"") {
    print(row)
}
```

Results:

```
[Optional("Lion Air")]
[Optional("Malindo Air")]
```

I tried:

```
if let a = row {
    print(a)
}
```

but it shows the error:

> 'Statement.Element' (aka 'Array<Optional<Binding>>')

How can I unwrap that array string and just leave as string as usual?

Comment: Read apple documentation.

Comment: Here are useful links to start: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

try these and see:

```
// According to your current result
for arrayElement in row {
  print(arrayElement)

  if let arrayString = arrayElement.first {
    print(arrayString)
  }

}
```

Try this for proper solution:

```
for childArray in row {
   print("childArray - \(childArray)")
   for stringValue in childArray {
       print("stringValue - \(stringValue)")
   }
}
```

Here is tested solution

```
let row = [
 [Optional("Lion Air")],
 [Optional("Malindo Air")]
]


row.forEach { (childArray) in
    childArray.forEach({ (optinalString) in
        print("optinalString - \(String(describing: optinalString))")

        if let unoptionalString = optinalString {
            print("unoptionalString - \(unoptionalString)")
        }
    })
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @themasmul None of the are what you want since all of these only give you the first value.

Comment: @rmaddy - I agree with you, even I have a doubt, these are wrong. I need to correct

Comment: @themasmul - try with an updated answer, previous one was providing only first element of array. But your variable `row` is an array of array<String>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using `flatMap`

Here is example optional string array to string array using `flatMap`

```
let optarray = [Optional("Swift"),Optional("Java"),Optional("C"), nil]
let stringArray = optarray.flatMap{$0}
print(stringArray)
```

**Output**

```
["Swift", "Java", "C"]
```