# Initialising mandatory properties in child class initialiser - Swift

Tags: swift, initialization, option-type

Heres my class hierarchy:

```
class Parent {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    init(dict: [String: Any]) {
        age = dict["age"] as! Int
    }//ERROR: "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"
}

class Child: Parent {
    var school: String
    override init(dict: [String: Any]) {
        school = dict["school"] as! String
        super.init(dict: dict)

        name = dict["childname"] as! String
    }
}
```

If I initialise `name` property in `Parent` initialiser then it's working, but in my situation I want it to initialise in `Child` only.

Is there any way to handle this?

P.S. there are lots of properties in `Parent` like `name` those should be initialised in `Child`

Comment: That makes no sense, creating a Parent object must initialize all properties. If `name` exists only in a Child then make it a property of Child.

Comment: There is absolutely no way to achieve what you want. An init method must initialise all the members.

Answer (score 2):

`Class/Struct` properties can't be nil/null. You must initialize `Class/Struct` properties at the time of declare or inside `Class/Struct's` `initializers`. If you want properties remain nil/null and want to populate them later, you have to declare your variable/reference as [Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift).

In your case make your `name` variable of `Parent` class as `Optional` like this `var name: String?`.

```
class Parent {
var name: String?
var age: Int
init(dict: [String: Any]) {
    age = dict["age"] as! Int
}
}

class Child: Parent {
var school: String
override init(dict: [String: Any]) {
    school = dict["school"] as! String
     super.init(dict: dict)
     name = dict["childname"] as! String
}
}

let dict: [String: Any] = ["childname":"Mamun", "school":"school name", 
"age": 12]
let child = Child(dict: dict)
print("Child name: \(child.name!)")
```