# fixing - Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode10, forced-unwrapping

I am new to coding and have been trying to make an area on the screen that I can sign with my finger. I have made the box but I am struggling to clear it. I have made a button connected to a function to clear the path but I can't seem to work out how to safely unwrap the information without it crashing.

```
import UIKit

class canvasView: UIView {

    var lineColour:UIColor!
    var lineWidth:CGFloat!
    var path:UIBezierPath!
    var touchPoint:CGPoint!
    var startingPoint:CGPoint!


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false

        lineColour = UIColor.white
        lineWidth = 10
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        startingPoint = (touch?.location(in: self))!
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        touchPoint = touch?.location(in: self)

        path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: startingPoint)
        path.addLine(to: touchPoint)
        startingPoint = touchPoint

        drawShapelayer()
    }
    func drawShapelayer(){
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColour.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func clearCanvas() {
        path.removeAllPoints()
        self.layer.sublayers = nil
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
```

I then get the error in my final function after

```
path.removeAllPoints()
```

How is best to unwrap it to stop it crashing?

Thank you for your patience

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if the user clicks the button to clear the canvas **before** he/she draws anything, then the error will occur, since `path` is only assigned a value in `touchesMoved()`.

You might want to change

```
var path:UIBezierPath!
```

to

```
var path:UIBezierPath?
```

Though this may seem tedious since you have to add question marks everywhere you try to access a method or property of `path`, it's much safer, and the code in your example will not crash.

P.S. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026093/8560567). It provides a lot of information regarding the use of optionals.

Comment: Thank you for that. it seems to remove one error and give me another. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT). I will have to look at it again and try and work out where I am going wrong.

Comment: No problem. You can post your error in another question and I can have a look at it :)