# Image full screen width in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I added an image to my body in a SwiftUI application and want to have that image cover the full width of the device, but not go over it.

In `body`, I return the image object:

```
var body: some View {
    Image("page-under-construction")
}
```

and the image shows up, however, it's too big:

[image]

I tried setting the frame: that affects the highlighted boundaries, but the image does not resize.
In combination, I played around with `.aspectRatio(contentMode:)`, which did not seem to have any effect on the layout.

How can I have the image be effectively 100% of the screen width?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The reason `.aspectRatio(contentMode:)` had no effect on the layout is because you did not make the image resizable with `resizeable()`.

Doing

```
var body: some View {
    Image("page-under-construction")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
}
```

will cause the image to be the width of the screen, but the image's aspect ratio will not be maintained. To maintain the aspect ratio, do

```
var body: some View {
    Image("page-under-construction")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(UIImage(named: "page-under-construction")!.size, contentMode: .fill)
}
```

This utilizes the `.aspectRatio(aspectRatio: CGSize, contentMode: ContentMode)` version of the method your original question discussed with a dummy UIImage to access the Image's original aspect ratio.

Note: The explicitly unwrapped optional (`!`) should not be a problem unless you are unsure if the image name is a valid one from your Assets folder. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift) for a comprehensive overview on Swift optionals.

Comment: I actually did find & try out `.resizable`, even in combination with `.aspectRatio`, but I did not provide `aspectRatio:  CGSize`. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 22):

Here is how you add a background image and make it fill the full screen in SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for `edgesIgnoringSafeArea`

Answer (score 8):

Did you try resizable modifier?

```
struct ImageView: View {
var body: some View {
    Image("turtlerock")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
}}
```

Note - There are 2 content modes: .fit and .fill

Comment: I did, yes. The `.resizable()` modifier does indeed modify the image - it even has options for tiling or stretching the image - but then the image is not in its original aspect ratio. I combined that with the `.aspectRatio` modifier like you did, but that does not affect the image at all for me...

Comment: I think this one should be the answer, just use content mode as .fit will do the thing.