# Optional in Swift

Tags: swift

I have some code in Swift on repl.it

```
let name = readLine()
print("Hello, \(name)!")
```

When I run it, I type in my name, and then it says "Hello, Optional("Andrew")!". I tried making the variable an optional string, like so:

```
let name: String? = readLine()
print("Hello, \(name)!")
```

Same result. What is wrong, and how do I avoid these errors?

Comment: Please read [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) in the Swift Language Guide. And as you are a beginner you are encouraged to read the entire Guide 

Comment: Note the print output `Optional("Andrew")!` does not mean the string is equal to that; what you're seeing there is the output of the `debugDescription` for that value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an optional value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error, that's how optionals work!

Clearly the `readline()` function returns an optional string, which is why you have the issue in the first call.

`readline()`'s method signature is:

```
func readLine(strippingNewline: Bool = true) -> String?
```

So it will always return an optional string.

So if you wish to print without optionals just do:

```
print("Hello, \(name!)!")
```

You could also follow best practice and safely 'unwrap':

```
if let name = readLine() {
  print(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should safely unwrap optionals:

```
if let name = readLine() {
  print(name)
}
```

or

```
guard let name = readLine() else { return }
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` can most likely also return `nil` — that's why an optional `String` is returned.

Use [optional binding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) so that you only use the `name` if it actually contains a value.

```
if let name = readLine() {
    print("Hello, \(name)!")
}
```